# Sinatra "can't convert nil into Hash" on multipart form submission

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to do a simple file upload page but keep getting "can't convert nil into Hash" (file: request.rb location: merge line: 221). This happens on Windows and Ubuntu. Ruby 1.9.3, Sinatra 1.3.2. What I also notice is that POST data is apparently empty, and regardless of the size file I try to upload the request is always just under 70k.

The handler isn't doing much:

```
get "/upload" do
  erb :upload
end      


post '/upload' do
  tempfile = params['file'][:tempfile]
  filename = params['file'][:filename]
  File.copy(tempfile.path, "./files/#{filename}")
  redirect '/'
end
```

the form looks like:

```
   <div id="bodydiv">
    <h1>file upload page</h1>
    File to upload:

    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="file" />
        <input type="hidden" value="tokenstuff" id="hiddenThing" />
        <input type="submit" value="upload" id="commit" />
    </form>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `name` attribute to your file input.
I don't why though, if someone can explain this. Thanks.